# Deferred not working at all with asynchronous Ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I have multiple HTML lists populated by Ajax async requests. When all those requests are finished (there are many of them), I need to populate the form by selecting the list items that correspond to my customer record.

I'm trying to use deferreds to accomplish this, but the function ends up firing long before the lists are populated. Any ideas?

```
$.when(
    $.ajax({
        url: "get-status.php",
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (j) {
            var options = ''; 
            $.each(j, function(key, value) { 
                options += '<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>';
            });     
            $("select#status_id").html(options);                
        }
    }),
    $.ajax({
        url: "get-groups.php",
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (j) {
            var options = ''; 
            $.each(j, function(key, value) { 
                options += '<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>';
            });     
            $("select#group_id").html(options);             
        }
    })                      
).then(populateForm('form1',customer_id));
```

Actual application code:

```
<!-- Main function -->  
populateFormBoxSS = function(id){
    $.ajax({
        url: "get-json-fich_ss.php?id="+id,
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (j) {         
            // Populate drop-downs              
            $.when(populateEstadosTest('box-estado_id')).then(populateFormGeneric(j, "box"));   
        }
    });         
}   
<!-- Generic Form Population -->
populateFormGeneric = function (j, target) {
    $.each(j, function(key, value) { 
        switch ($('#'+target+'-'+key).attr('type')) {
            case 'checkbox':
                if(value==1) {
                    $('#'+target+'-'+key).attr('checked', true);
                }
                break;                      
            default:
                $('#'+target+'-'+key).val(value);
                break;                  
        }                                           
    });     
    return function(){
        // Do nothing
    }
}
<!-- Dropdown list population -->   
populateEstadosTest = function(field){
    var dfd = new $.Deferred();     
    $.ajax({
        url: "get-json-esta.php",
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (j) {
                var options = ''; 
                $.each(j, function(key, value) { 
                    options += '<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>';
                });     
                $("select#"+field).html(options);
                // Resolve Deferred
                dfd.resolve();              
        }
    }); 
    return dfd.promise(); // Returns a promise              
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does populateForm('form1') return a function? Deferred .then expects a callback function e.g. like that:

```
var populateForm = function (j, target) {
    return function() {
        $.each(j, function(key, value) { 
            switch ($('#'+target+'-'+key).attr('type')) {
                case 'checkbox':
                    if(value==1) {
                        $('#'+target+'-'+key).attr('checked', true);
                    }
                    break;                      
                default:
                    $('#'+target+'-'+key).val(value);
                    break;                  
            }                                           
        });
    }     
}

$.when(
    $.ajax({
        url: "get-status.php",
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (j) {
            var options = ''; 
            $.each(j, function(key, value) { 
                options += '<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>';
            });     
            $("select#status_id").html(options);                
        }
    }),
    $.ajax({
        url: "get-groups.php",
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (j) {
            var options = ''; 
            $.each(j, function(key, value) { 
                options += '<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>';
            });     
            $("select#group_id").html(options);             
        }
    })                      
).then(populateForm('form1',customer_id));
```

Comment: The thing is, I don't really need to do anything with the xhr objects. I'm just looking for a way to be sure all ajax functions are complete before executing populateForm(). Is there an alternative way? This should be a pretty common scenario, but I'm new to JQuery and I haven't been able to find a solution.

Comment: You still have to return a callback (callback functions *are* a pretty common thing). You can omit the parameters if you are not using them though.

Comment: Hi Daff, and thank you for your answer. I tried adding a return function, but the populateForm function still executes before time. Let me add the actual code to the original question (I originally simplified it so It wouldn't be so long).

Comment: It would be more interesting to see how your current populateForm looks like.

Comment: Hello Daff, my current populateForm is the function populateFormGeneric() that appears in the updated code of my original message.

Comment: That's great, thank you so much @Daff! I've been going mad over the last 3 days trying to get it to work. You've been an enormous help. **Thanks again!**